# ServerAlias in apache, ubuntu

Tags: apache, ubuntu, virtualhost

I have a virtual host in ubuntu on apache, this is not my main config, i have another web page as my main, so i wanted to set this one up on the same IP using a virtual host.

urologyexpert.mx is my server name, and this works perfect, but i want to have several aliases to access this page

I put as server alias:
www.urologyexpert.mx (doesn't work)
urologoexpertomonterrey.mx (doesn't work)
www.urologoexpertomonterrey.mx (working)

The one's that does not work gets routed to my default webpage on this IP,

here's my apache config in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled

A records are set up for urologyexpert.mx and urologoexpertomonterrey.mx, both pointing at the same IP, and i have a CNAME for www for urologyexpert.mx

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName urologyexpert.mx
    ServerAlias www.urologyexpert.mx, urologoexpertomonterrey.mx, www.urologoexpertomonterrey.mx

    DocumentRoot /var/www/urologyexpert.mx
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/urologyexpert.mx>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride All
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Can someone help me with this? i just can't figure out why one alias is working and two aren't

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I actually know now what was the problem,

The multiple ServerAlias have to be separated by a space, and not a comma, thats why only the ServerName and the last Alias was working

```
ServerAlias www.urologyexpert.mx urologoexpertomonterrey.mx www.urologoexpertomonterrey.mx
```

I hope this helps someone